# phonegap Ajax Call returns error=undefined in android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

i have enabled CORS, tried both get and post method,at first the ajax call was working fine but now it works fine in the browser but when I test it on my device it goes into the error function and i get 
error=undefined 
any help would be appreciated

```
 $("#createEvent_btn").click(function(e) {
//alert("in the function ");
if ($("#registerInfo").valid()) {
    $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
    start = $("#startDate").val();
    end = $("#endDate").val();
    venue = $("#place").val();
    var data2 = $("#registerInfo").serialize();
    var params = data2;
    alert(params);
    //console.log(data2);
    var url = 'http://domain/th/registerEvent.php';
    //ajax.open("POST", url, true);
    //ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    //ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    var modurl = url + "?" + params;
    alert(modurl);
    ajax.open("GET", modurl, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200 || ajax.status == 0) {
            //alert(ajax.response);
            id = ajax.response;
            alert(id);
            $('#createEvent_btn').removeClass('ui-disabled');
            setPeoplepage();
        }
    };
    ajax.onerror = function(e) {
        alert("Error ocurred. Error = " + e);
    };
    ajax.send(params);
}
```

});

Comment: have you verified whitelist setting in config.xml ?

Comment: yes I did, by adding <access origin="*" />

Answer (score 0):

use device ready function

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: all of my code is in device ready function, the app is working fine on samsung note but not on tablet